# Integrating Google reCaptcha v3 into Angular app with ng-recaptcha

Tags: angular, recaptcha-v3

I'd like to protect a register page from automatic submitions, so I decided to try reCaptcha v3. It's an Angular application, and I'm using [ng-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha#example-v3-all-actions) module for easier integration. I've set up a basic example on Stackblitz so you can test it online:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qk3jhr

I have a couple of doubts/problems:

1. If I write my valid Google key into the `app.module.ts` file, when I press the submit button, the `this.recaptchaV3Service.execute` call does nothing. Is it because the app is not in the domain I stated when generating reCaptcha V3 keys? Also, if I write a wrong key, Google complains with the following error:

> Error: Invalid site key or not loaded in api.js:

2. Once I'd get the token, what do i do with it? I've read the ng-recaptcha documentation but I don't see anything about it. I mean, when I have the token, what do I need to do to check if it's valid and send the form?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 15):

Finally, I got some time to try some things and I managed to make it work. Basically, what I did is:

1 Generate a pair of keys for testing (setting 'localhost' in the domain).

2 In the client app, I've set up the `ng-recaptcha` module as explained in its page (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha#recaptcha-v3-usage-see-in-action). Then, from the user registration component (which I want to protect), I run the following code when pressing the 'Submit' button:

```
public beforeSubmittingForm(): void {
    this.recaptchaV3Service.execute('registerSubmit').subscribe(
        (token) => {
            // 'this.user' contains the data of the user we want to create. Add the received token
            this.user.recaptchav3_token = token;    

            this.submitForm();  // This sends the user data to the backend
        },
        (error) => {
            this.errors = [ 'Error trying to verify request (reCaptcha v3)' ];
        });
}
```

3 In the backend, in the user registration route, I use the `axios` library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make a POST request to the Google verify service with the received token:

```
try {
    var result = await axios.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", {}, {
        params: {
            secret: recaptcha_api_key,  // Secret API key
            response: req.body.recaptchav3_token    // Received token from the frontend
        }
    });

    if(result.score < 0.5) {
        return res.status(403).json({ msg: 'Google Recaptcha error' });
    }
} catch(e) {
    return res.status(403).json({ msg: 'Error trying to verify the request' });
}
// Continue with the registration process...
```

Hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the first question. If you use an invalid key then it's expected you'll get that error. If you use the correct key for the correct domain, the token should be generated.

For the 2nd question... there's really no need generate a token during `ngOnInit()` in this case because you're generating a token in your `preSubmitForm()` method, and that is sufficient. As to what to do with the token, you will need to post it along with the rest of the form data to your server. Then in your server-side code where the form submit is handled, make a request to the recaptcha API providing both the token and your secret key.

Take a look at [Google's reCaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) in regard to server side validation.

Comment: Hi! What I was trying to say with the first question is that I don't get any response from the server (neither success nor error) when I use the correct key, but I do get an error if I use a wrong one. Anyway, I had to advance other features of the application and I didn't have time to do more tests. I'll dedicate some time over the following days and I'll post what I find. Thanks!