# AngularJS1 google reCaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, recaptcha, angularjs-1.7

Can anyone help me how to implement the google recaptcha.
I have already register and have my own site key and secret key.

I'm using AngularJS 1.7.9 and asp.net core web api.

I am having also an issue of "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute". I believe angularjs is generating cookies and some of them, tag the same site to none and string empty, and also security is unchecked.

[list of affected cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46OXc.png)

[list of cookies and look at there tag as security is unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQX7Y.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating Google reCaptcha v3 into Angular app with ng-recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476993/integrating-google-recaptcha-v3-into-angular-app-with-ng-recaptcha)

Comment: Hi Jelle, its actually in typescript. I follow the steps but its not applicable in angularjs1.7.9